# Confuse about Begin() method as param

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I create a simple program

```
void method_2(int* arr, int* first, int * last){
// algorithm
}

void method_1(int arr[]){
method_2(arr, std::begin(arr), std::end(arr)); // No matching function for call begin()

}
```

Guys Why I'm getting "No matching function for call begin()" compiling error ? How can i solve this problem.

Comment: `arr` is a pointer, there is no `begin` method for pointers. Simply way to solve it is to use a vector instead of a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

This code is legal but deceptive

```
void method_1(int arr[]){
```

It looks as if `arr` is an array but it isn't. In C and C++ it is not possible to pass an array to a function. A pointer is used instead of an array. So the code above is exactly the same as

```
void method_1(int* arr){
```

That's the background. The problem is that although `std::begin` works for arrays it does not work for pointers, so

```
void method_1(int arr[]){
    method_2(arr, std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
```

is not legal because `arr` is a pointer.

The root of the problem is that it is impossible to know from a pointer, pointing at an array of items, how many items it is pointing at.

How to fix it depends on what you are trying to do, there are many possibilities. The simple and standard one in C++ is to avoid arrays and pointers altogetther and use `std::vector` instead. One of the many advantages of `std::vector` is that you know how many items are in the vector at all times, so `begin`, `end` and `size` all work as expected.